# Current day and select ring invisible - DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, android-datepicker

i have currenlty some issue with the DatePickerDialog. You can see on the screen below that the current in invisible or in blank, same as the select ring.

[image]

**Activity** :

```
dialog = new DatePickerDialog(profilFragment.getActivity(), R.style.WeezyuTheme_DatePickerDialog, this,
                            year, month, day);
```

**Style XML** :

```
<style name="WeezyuTheme.DatePickerDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#0f0</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#f00</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#00f</item>
</style>
```

So if you have any idea to resolve it.

Comment: Change color codes in styles, these all 3 are white.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the reason behind this but it would be better if you apply these color codes in colors.xml file and then refer those colors here.

Like 
In colors.xml file, change the values as:

```
<color name="colorAccent">#0f0</color>
<color name="colorPrimary">#f00</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00f</color>
```

And then change the values in style.xml as:

```
<style name="WeezyuTheme.DatePickerDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Hope this will help.